# What does it mean 100% disk usage in Task Manager?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, task-manager

I see the following picture in Task Manager about my Drive C:

[image]

As you see, active is 100% most of the time, while disk transfer rate is relatively low and below 10 Mb/s.

How to understand this? What is used by 100% if transfer is low? How to know, who is providing this usage?

Comment: Were you doing something that caused a lot of writing to the disk? It's impossible to see what was using the disk at the time, now that it has passed. The only thing the graph can really tell is is you had minimum to moderate disk usage, then something began read or write to the disk at 100% utilization.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates a lot of disk activity.  It could either be a problem with a highly fragmented drive (ie lots of small files scattered all over the disk), and/or a disk failure.

You should do a S.M.A.R.T test to see if your disk is failing, and spending a lot of time trying to reread sectors.    Unfortunately a failing disk is a far more likely explanation of the provided data.

Comment: I have changed disk to a new one but situation persists. This is probably due to `superfetch`, but does it really require to touch my disk all the time?

Comment: You changed disks?  What does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your write speed, it is 94.6k/s, which is atrociously bad.

Of course, if you happen to be saving many, many small files, that's fine.

However, if that's not what you did, this indicates a problem with writing to the disk.

Comment: How to know which problem?